# How do I stop my Azure Redis implementation from causing a Newtonsoft Self referencing loop error?

Tags: c#, redis, azure-functions, azure-redis-cache

I'm currently trying to implement a solution to read and write data to an Azure Redis cache.  For the most part the implementation is complete however, when I attempt to read the redis cache I get an error of:

> An unhandled host error has occured Newtonsoft.Json: Self referencing
> loop detected for property 'target' with type
> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder'
> 1+AsyncStateMachineBox'1[System.String,
> MyProject.Service.CarData.RedisCachService+d__2]'.
> Path 'moveNextAction'.

Here is my code so far.

**Method**

```
private readonly IRedisService _redisService;

public Car(IRedisService redisService)
{
    _redisService = redisService;
}

[FunctionName("GetCarData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCarData([HttpTrigger(AuthorisationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/car/get")] HttpRequest req)
{
    var data = _redisService.GetCarDataAsync("testId")
    return new OkObjectResult(data)
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface IRedisService
{
    Task<string> GetCarDataAsync(string key)
}
```

**Service**

```
private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _conn;

public RedisService(IConnectionMultiplexer conn)
{ 
    _conn = conn;
}

public async Task<string> GetCarDataAsync(string key)
{    
    var data = _conn.GetDatabase();
    return await db.StringGetAsync(key);
}
```

**Startup**

```
// Redis Information
services.AddSingleton<IRedisService, RedisService>();
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(x =>
    ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("Azure Redis host],abortConnection=false,ssl=true,password=[Primary Access Key]")
)
```

As this is a very basic function that simply requests data based on a key and also my first time implementing this, I'm not sure exactly what is causing the problem.  Typically I've seen similar with models which reference each other but this is not the same.  Has anyone had this before or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Post the *full* exception text, not just parts of it. Post the relevant code too. Which one of these snippets comes from `RedisCachService` ? The error sounds as if the serializer tried to serialize the service or controller instead of the unspecified data class.

Comment: That is the FULL exception text, it's the only information it gives me about it.

Comment: You aren't actually awaiting the service response for starters: `var data = _redisService.GetCarDataAsync("testId")`